# Grover, CCZ Gate on IBM Quantum Lab & unexpected outputs

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

Studying Grover on IBM lab using Qiskit. But the following code produces unexpected outputs. Note that `PhaseOracle produces 2 CCZ gates. Could anyone check (and explain) why are those unexpected counts/outputs(given at the bottom) being produced?

Note that when I try a similar code with similar logical expressions with aqua (which is deprecated, the expected outputs are produced)

```python
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle
from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem
%matplotlib inline

matplotlib inline
oracle = PhaseOracle('((A & C) | (B & D)) & ~(C & D)')
problem = AmplificationProblem(oracle=oracle, is_good_state=oracle.evaluate_bitstring)
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
grover = Grover(quantum_instance=backend)
result = grover.amplify(problem)
print(result.circuit_results[0])
{'0111': 259, '1100': 244, '1101': 234, '0011': 287}
```

Comment: Note that; if I set up the circuit manually, I can achieve correct results with expected probabilities. For example, I can catch 100% "111" with a manually created circuit with 3 qbits. (for a logical expression like (A&B&C) However, the code given above below not return 111 with 100% probability.

Comment: from qiskit import * from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem %matplotlib inline

matplotlib inline oracle = PhaseOracle('((A & B & C)') problem = AmplificationProblem(oracle=oracle, is_good_state=oracle.evaluate_bitstring) backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') grover = Grover(quantum_instance=backend) result = grover.amplify(problem) print(result.circuit_results[0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit Terra internally uses [Tweedledum](https://github.com/boschmitt/tweedledum) library to parse logical expressions. By default, Tweedledum sort the variables by the order of their appearance in the logical expressions. In your case, the order is `A` then `C` then `B` and finally `D`. So, you should interpret the output bitstring as `DBCA`.

On the other hand, in Qiskit Aqua's `LogicalExpressionOracle` the variables used to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now.

Comment: What about A & B & C ? ** Following does not produce the result 111 with 100% certainty.. **      --> from qiskit import * from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram from qiskit.circuit.library import PhaseOracle from qiskit.algorithms import Grover, AmplificationProblem %matplotlib inline matplotlib inline oracle = PhaseOracle('((A & B & C)') problem = AmplificationProblem(oracle=oracle, is_good_state=oracle.evaluate_bitstring) backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') grover = Grover(quantum_instance=backend) result = grover.amplify(problem) print(result.circuit_results[0])

Comment: **However, following circuit (manually created) produce the result 111 with %100 probability. **            ---->  circuit2=QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circuit2.h(0)
circuit2.h(1)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.ccx(0,1,2)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.z(0)
circuit2.z(1)
circuit2.z(2)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.ccx(0,1,2)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.h(0)
circuit2.h(1)
circuit2.h(2)
circuit2.measure([0,1,2],[0,1,2])